# How to formally explain the use of Maclaurin expansion when working with polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, taylor-expansion

I have task: Find such polynomials $ u(x) $, $ v(x) $, that
$$
 x^m u(x) + (1-x)^nv(x) = 1 
$$

I understand that we can calculate the formal derivatives of $u(x)$ and $v(x)$ up to $n-1$ and $m-1$ at the point $1$ and $0$ accordingly, and then expand each polynomial according to Maclaurin at this point.

My question is how to formally explain the use of the Maclaurin expansion in this problem, because in the general case, defining polynomials as functions is not entirely correct (for example, it is useful to distinguish between the polynomials $P(x) = $ and $Q(x) = x^p$ over the field $Z_p$, however for any $x \in Z_p$ the equality $P(x) = Q(x)$ holds. In lectures we defined polynomials as finite sequences (sequence $(a_0, a_1,\ldots)$
elements from  is called finite if it contains a finite number of non-zero elements
cops). And the formal derivatives are like this: Let $P = p_0 + p_1x + \ldots + p_nx^n \in F[x]$. Formal derivative
of the polynomial () is called the polynomial $P' := p_1+2p_2x+ \ldots +np_nx^{n−1}$, where the integers
scalars are understood as sums of the corresponding number of units.